# How to embed an image with text in an RichFaces a4j:commandButton

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I would like to have both an image and text (from the `value` attribute) in an `a4j:commandButton` in my JSF page, is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: how do you expect this to look?

Comment: like a one element table with an image, and with vertical-middle aligned text to it's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define the image as CSS background image.

```
.buttonclass {
    background-image: url('foo.gif');
}
```

You don't want to use the image attribute to just only have a background image. This will render a HTML `<input type="image">` which has an entirely different purpose (an image map which will return X and Y position of the mouse pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Using the image attribute of the `a4j:commandButton` tag causes the component to ignore any enclosed output text tag.  Including an `h:graphicImage` tag deposits the image but not as part of what is rendered as the button.

The best way to overcome the problem is to create a new button containing both the test and the image and use the image property of the `a4j:commandButton`.

@BalusC: Good point re input type, but setting a button class as listed in your answer and using

```
                <a4j:commandButton styleClass="btnStop" type="button"
                    disabled="true" ignoreDupResponses="true" reRender="lastOp"
                    onclick="this.disabled=true" alt="myAlt" value="myVal"
                    oncomplete="this.disabled=false" action="#{MyBacking.action}" />
```

creates a button and the image is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Then the URL of the image is plain wrong. Keep in mind that it is relative to the URL of the CSS file where it is definied in. In the future, please post that as a comment instead of as an answer, else it will get lost in noise.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found a quick solution with a4j:commandButton. However I use the equivalent a4j:commandLink

```
<a4j:commandLink action="..." type="submit"
   oncomplete="..." styleClass="buttonLink">
 <h:graphicImage url="/img/icons/save12x12.gif" /> Update</a4j:commandLink>
```

with the following stylesheet

```
  <u:selector name="a.buttonLink">
    <u:style name="padding" value="2px 4px"/>
    <u:style name="background-image">
      <f:resource f:key="org.richfaces.renderkit.html.GradientA"/>
    </u:style>
    <u:style name="background-position" value="0px 50%"/>
    <u:style name="border" value="1px solid"/>
    <u:style name="border-color" skin="headerBackgroundColor"/>
    <u:style name="font-family" skin="generalFamilyFont"/>
    <u:style name="font-size" value="11px"/>
    <u:style name="font-weight" value="bold"/>
    <u:style name="color" skin="headerTextColor"/>
    <u:style name="text-decoration" value="none"/>
  </u:selector>

  <u:selector name="a.buttonLink:active, a.buttonLink:link, a.buttonLink:visited">
    <u:style name="color" skin="headerTextColor"/>
    <u:style name="text-decoration" value="none"/>
  </u:selector>
```

haven't tested it with IE (not using it) but works fine with firefox..